# what is the difference between += and =+ in ruby?"

Tags: ruby, unary-operator

The += and =+ is not working as I would expect. The following code outputs the correct value for @@num_things.

```
   class Thing
     @@num_things = 0 # class variable

     def initialize()
       @@num_things += 1 # increment @@num_things
     end

     def value
       @@num_things
     end

   end

   t1 =Thing.new()
   puts t1.value
   t2 =Thing.new()
   puts t2.value
   t3 =Thing.new()
   puts t3.value
```

The output is :

```
   1
   2
   3
```

However, if you invert the expression from += to be =+ now the output becomes

```
   1
   1
   1
```

What am i missing? I would expect the output to be the same in both cases once the value is called.

Comment: Ruby's convention is to omit empty argument lists, so `new()` becomes simply `new`. It's less syntax, easier to follow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such token as `=+`; it's actually *two* tokens: assignment followed by the unary `+` operator; the latter is essentially a no-op, so `@@num_things =+ 1` is equivalent to `@@num_things = 1`.

Since there is a `+=` token, the language parser will parse it as a single token.

(In the early formulations of BCPL which was the precursor to C, the modern `-=` operator was written as `=-`.)

Comment: Interesting, I thought the operator (=+) existed like it does in Java , but that does not seem to be the case. Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I’ll defer to your expertise; I have used the term token instead.

Comment: Bathsheba, you anticipated my comments. Whether `=+` (and more generally `=o`, where  `o` is any binary operator) is an operator is somewhat contested. Many references, such as [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators), lists `=+` as an operator. However, [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html) and authoritative books such as [The Ruby Programming Language](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/the-ruby-programming/9780596516178/ch04s05.html) (p. 95) refer to such constructs as *abbreviated assignment*. (cont.)

Comment: ...As `x =+ y` is expanded to `x = x + y` when Ruby code is parsed, it seems to me to be a form of [syntactic sugar](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/02/20/ruby-magic-syntactic-sugar-methods.html), which argues against it being called an operator. To make things more confusing, while Ruby docs list its operators (most of which are implemented as methods), I do not believe it actually defines what constitutes an operator.

Comment: @CristianContreras This operator, `=+`, doesn't exist in Java.  You might be able to create it with an operator overload in Scala or Kotlin, but not in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Here's why:

`y += x` is the same as `y = x + y`.  `+=` works in Ruby like it does in so many other programming languages.

`y =+ x` is the same as `y = +x` is the same as `y = x`.  Ruby sees `=+` as two operators, not one.  This also holds for negative values of `x`, too.